# Should we recommend deletion of a low quality post if it has a comment suggesting how to improve it?

Tags: discussion, answer-quality

Sorry, I wasn't able to frame the question in a short and easy to understand format.

I see that there are posts like [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/117807) in the review queue. They are marked as low quality posts and have comments on how to improve the answer.

Now the user will either ignore that comment or update the answer according to the comment. At the time of review, we can't know if the user has seen the comment and made a decision on it so we can't be sure if the post will be improved or not.

So should we recommend the deletion of the post as at the time of review it was genuinely low quality or should we just skip it and let there be a chance that someone else will see it later and hopefully the author would have made a decision?

I wonder if it would be a good idea to have a snooze button for such posts. Wait for a community defined fixed time. If the author hasn't updated the answer by then, well too late.

Comment: You can get a reasonable approximation of whether the user has seen the comment by looking at the "Last seen" field on their profile which will tell you approximately when the user was last active. (As far as I recall the granularity of that field is 15 minutes.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that posts should be evaluated based on their present state. Canned suggestions for improvements, especially on link-only answers, are most likely to be ignored or unheard.

Should the author heed the suggestion, deletion will not prevent them from improving their post: deleted answers are still editable, and a post deleted via "recommend deletion" review actions [can be single-handedly undeleted by the author](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226993/answers-deleted-via-recommend-deletion-votes-in-review-should-not-be-undeletable/228479#228479).

Comment: I did not know the undeletion part. Thanks!

Comment: posts should be evaluated based on their present state, yes, but isn't it so that deletion should be reserved for posts beyond improving? If they can be made worthy with a suggested fix, shouldn't they be maybe downvoted, but not deleted..?

Answer (score 3):

Deleting immediately can be a hit to morale. I tend to wait at least 12 hours after suggestions have been made for improvement or at least until I know the user has had a chance to read and respond. This is a personal choice. I do like the "grace period" button, though.

Flagging for undeletion aside, I think it is ok to let post linger in the review queue so that users do not feel cut off.

Comment: There is a grace period button? Either I have completely missed it, or this is a moderators only function.

Comment: @Anders I was referencing the button mentioned by the OP. It does not exist.